# Generating the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a tuple made by RandomFunction

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions, random-process

I use the RandomFunction to generate a continuous random function (trying to model a rough surface):

```
r = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 10, 0.01}];
ListLinePlot[r, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

I'm able to plot the histogram by:

```
Histogram[r, 0.2]
```

[image]

But when I try to make a CDF of the data it is empty:

```
s = CDF[r, x];
Plot[s, {x, -10, 10}, Filling -> Axis]
```

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: Maybe `s = CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[r], x];` ?

Comment: @kglr It seems `EmpiricalDistribution` immediately deals with the `TemporalData` in a sensible fashion.

Comment: @b.gatessucks this actually worked fine

Comment: @gwr, right. But, in version 9, you need to use `EmpiricalDistribution[r["States][[1]]]`

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is a cumulative distribution function then you will have to make your run data a distribution. You may use [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) or [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html):

```
SeedRandom = ["March 13, 2018"];
r = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 10, 0.01}];

dist = EmpiricalDistribution @ r;
Plot[ Evaluate@CDF[ dist, x], {x, -10, 10}, 
    Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1000
]
```

[image: CDF]

Comment: I get this error `Syntax::sntxf: "SeedRandom=" cannot be followed by "[March 13, 2018]".` !

Comment: I think I did :) I will try again.

Comment: If I may ask a side question? How can I integrate over dist now? e.g. f(x)=int[dist,{u,-5,x}]

Comment: @Foad  But, that should be exactly what `CDF[ dist, x ]` will do. Manually you could integrate using `PDF[ dist, x]` or you could use `Probability`.